# PHP postgresql select, getting id of the one that follows the current one

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am getting 10 rows with the highest ID from a table ...

```
$result = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT w_news_id, name, w_newsnachricht, w_newsdatum FROM adempiere.w_news ORDER BY w_news_id DESC LIMIT 10");
```

... then I build 10 divs in a while loop:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) { 
    // building divs here
}
```

BUT I want to also include the **name** that belongs to the next **w_news_id** in that same div (as a "teaser" for the "next"-arrow). So I was thinking I have to run a second query with the ID that would be next in the loop.

How is the SQL syntax for that? Or is there maybe a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lead` [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT   w_news_id, name, w_newsnachricht, w_newsdatum,
         LEAD (name) OVER (ORDER BY w_news_id) AS next_name
FROM     adempiere.w_news 
ORDER BY w_news_id DESC 
LIMIT    10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select one more record - `LIMIT 11`, instead of `10`, and process it differently in PHP.

```
$result = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT w_news_id, name, w_newsnachricht, w_newsdatum FROM adempiere.w_news ORDER BY w_news_id DESC LIMIT 11");

$i = 0;
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result) and $i < 10) {
  $i++;
  // building divs here
}

// then process the arrow and teaser separately (if present)
if ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  // show teaser div
}
```

**UPDATE**

The window function solution provided by `Mureinik` is better.